# Differenze tra "a partire di" e "a partire da"

Tags: word-usage, difference, prepositions

Cercando su Google, ho trovato frasi sia con "a partire di" che con "a partire da". Non riesco a capire però quali siano le differenze di uso tra queste due espressioni. Me le potreste spiegare?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"A partire di" è sbagliato.

Delle frasi che si trovano in google con "a partire di", il 99% è sbagliato, e il resto sono frasi in cui è vero che le tre parole appaiono in sequenza ma sono parte di una frase più ampia e con un altro significato, ad esempio:

> Ho riparato la macchina e sono pronto a partire di nuovo
>
> Il libro "pronti a partire" di Mario Rossi.
>
> Di solito si tende a partire di mattina|lunedì.
>
> Con prezzi a partire, di solito, da 100 euro.

(ecc. ecc.) Quello che voglio dire è che l'espressione corretta è "a partire da".

Comment: Un altro indizio che il primo sia sbagliato è che "a partire di" (virgolettato) fornisce 85000 risultati, "a partire da" 23 milioni. E gli 85000 diventano meno di metà se si restringe la ricerca a site:it.

Answer (score 4):

Il complemento di moto da luogo può essere introdotto dalla preposizione *di*, ma solo in poche situazioni: *uscire di qui* è usato e corretto, *partire di qui* è meno usuale. Un ipotetico *partire di Milano* mi suonerebbe piuttosto antiquato, se non scorretto.

Secondo il [dizionario Treccani](http://treccani.it/vocabolario/di1/),

> Equivale in qualche caso alla preposizione *da* per indicare provenienza: *uscire di casa*, *venire di lontano*; e passaggio da uno stato all’altro: *di scolaro divenne maestro*; *andare di male in peggio*.

Sono quasi certo che *di* per la provenienza fosse più usato in passato. Non nella lingua attuale.